# Linguistic Terms Icons?

Tags: icon, resource-recommendations

Does anyone know of any linguistic terms icons (icons for "noun", "stem", "grammatical number", various grammatical cases), or preferably a package of them?

I know of the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com) and there are some icons from around the web and from various package (like [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com)) that I've used or created icons based off of icons from there.

I created some icons I need from scratch, too, but I'm looking for already-made icons, either intended for linguistic terms of that can be good icons for linguistic terms.

I know it's a bit vague, I just don't want to request specific icons, but find (a) source(s).

Answer (score 1):

Yes: the Montessori tradition defines a set of [grammar symbols](http://www.montessorialbum.com/montessori/index.php?title=Grammar_Symbols) for marking parts of speech:

[image: Montessori grammar symbols]
[image: Parts of speech in a sentence marked up with symbols]

Of course, the same can be done with [pop culture icons](https://i.etsystatic.com/6086771/r/il/99c33b/822365713/il_fullxfull.822365713_b3e8.jpg). Then there are various keyboardable [symbols used](https://www.departments.bucknell.edu/linguistics/lectures/natclass.html) for typing up features smaller than words.

Answer (score 0):

A bit impossible to find something so specific, but I don't see a very difficult job here. You have many elements to play with:

- Standard icons of this subject don't exist, so the person who visualizes them for the first time will have to learn them
- They have many graphic elements besides the meaning as (as far as I remember them):

  - hierarchy
  - position
  - function
- Depends on the use the design can be more or less graphic, such as a simple
  visual code

After reading the question, the first thing that occurred to me is this following the sentence structure, surely 100% improvable:

[image]

Comment: I probably forgot to mention in my question - I'm looking for graphical icons, ones without text. As for the users learning them - I'm aware of it, but still prefer ones that are as intuitive as possible while still capturing the meaning. As for the kinds - I'm looking mostly for grammatical cases, but icons for other linguistic terms might be useful as well as I might use them.

Comment: Ok, you should add all this info at the question and maybe a list of minimum 10 cases. But intuitive images for grammatical cases? For this a gram. case must be intuitive and it's not, it's pure mathematics.

Comment: How about repurposing mathematical expressions such as (=,+,<,>,%,#) there are many more 'scientific' versions and are mostly available through your keyboard.

Comment: @Danielillo I'm looking for anything that might be useful, I might inspiration from suggestions/icons and make icons myself.

About using existing existing scientific ones - many of them don't have a graphic relation to their meaning, so I don't think they'd be useful.